# Managing multiple Pods with one Deploy

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

Good afternoon, I need help defining a structure of my production cluster, i want something like.

- 1 Deployment that controlled the pods
- multiple PODS (one pod per-customer)
- multiple services (one service-per pod)

but how will I do this structure if for each POD I have env vars that will connect to the customer database, like that

```
env:
    - name: dbuser
      value: "svc_iafox_test@***"
    - name: dbpassword
      value: "****"
    - name: dbname
      value: "ts-demo1"
    - name: dbconnectstring
      value: "jdbc:sqlserver://***-test.database.windows.net:1433;database=$(dbname);user=$(dbuser);password=$(dbpassword);encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;"
```

so for each pod I will have to change these env vars ... anyway, what is the best way for me to do this??

Answer (score 0):

you could use configmap to achieve that:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "echo $(SPECIAL_LEVEL_KEY) $(SPECIAL_TYPE_KEY)" ]
      env:
        - name: SPECIAL_LEVEL_KEY
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: special-config
              key: SPECIAL_LEVEL
        - name: SPECIAL_TYPE_KEY
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: special-config
              key: SPECIAL_TYPE
  restartPolicy: Never
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#use-configmap-defined-environment-variables-in-pod-commands

ps. I dont think 1 deployment per pod makes sense. 1 deployment per customer does. I dont think you understand exactly what a deployment does: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/

Comment: I think you did not understand my problem, the problem is how I will make those multiple pods connect to my Deploy so they can be managed by this deploy, because when I replicate a deploy replicas did not load the env vars, and I can not edit a pod already created, ie I have to create the Pods separately

Comment: yeah, just stick a pod with configmap into a deployment. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment https://blog.bigbinary.com/2017/05/25/using-kubernetes-configmap-with-configuration-files-for-deploying-rails-app.html

Comment: about your ps, I do not want to have 1 deploy per pod, I want to have only 1 deploy that manages all the pods

Comment: that makes no sense, you cannot scale clients individually, so if only one client has more load, you need to scale all the client pods

Comment: but my application will not need scaling because it is targeted at small businesses, do you think you should still use the 1 deploy per customer approach?

Comment: lets put it this way, you dont sacrifice anything but you gain flexibility. why not? I dont see any downside to having 1 deployment per customer (even for 1 pod )